# How can I change the timezone of a date string?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I would like to change the timezone of a time like:

```
2015-08-24 01:30:40
```

so that it's in the `America/Los_Angeles` timezone, but the code below isn't working as expected:

```
$timedate = date_timezone_set(
              date_create_from_format('Y-m-d h:i:s A', $row[timezone]),
              new DateTimeZone('America/Los Angeles')
            );
```

`$row[timezone]` successfully returns `2015-08-24 01:30:40` on it's own, but when I do it like this to try to change the timezone, it doesn't work.

All PHP code after that doesn't run. I have done lots of searching, but I can't figure out how to get this to work properly so can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to date_create_from_format includes an A at the end of the format string - that looks specious to me, given that your value doesn't end with am or pm. Your use of `h` looks unlikely to be correct too, as that's for a 12-hour hour-of-day, which isn't useful when you don't have an am/pm indicator. I suspect you want a format of

```
Y-m-d H:i:s
```

That appears to match your sample string better...

*Additionally*, as noted in comments, your time zone ID should be `'America/Los_Angeles'` rather than `'America/Los Angeles'`.

I would also separate the various calls you have in this single large line of code, to make it easier to diagnose - that way you could tell that it's the parsing that's failing, rather than anything to do with the time zone. You have three separate operations here:

- Parse a string to a datetime
- Create a time zone object
- Set the time zone in the datetime

Keeping those three in separate statements will make the code easier to read and easier to maintain. (In particular, you'd be able to find and correct these two problems independently...)

Comment: Great answer, but OP's timezone is invalid. He has to change out that space between `Los` and `Angeles` with an underscore. (See: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php (<- Second column))

Comment: @Rizier123: Thanks, will add that a second problem.

Comment: Oh didn't see that. It still isn't in the format I wanted it though, because when I create the timezone earlier before putting it in the MySQL database, I use the Y-m-d h:i:s A format, but on the MySQL database, it s hows up as Y-m-d H:i:s.

Comment: Well I split it up into multiple parts and the part that isn't working is the date_create_from_format part.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally saved the comment before I finished typing...
`date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row[timestamp]);
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$timedate = date_timezone_set($date, $timezone);`
I also realized another mistake. Earlier, I had timezone instead of timestamp as the name of the database row so I fixed that.

Comment: I found another problem. I forgot to convert the DateTime to a string prior to displaying it. Using `$finaltimedate = $timedate->format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');` worked and displayed it in the format I wanted. Thank you for your help! :)